# 削除したリストが元に戻る

Tags: swift, ios, xcode

TodoListアプリを作っています。
リストからタスクをスワイプして削除した後、新しくタスクを追加すると削除したタスクが元に戻ってしまいます。
削除したままの状態にしたいのですが、どうしたら良いのでしょうか。。
回答いただけたら幸いです。
mac 10.15.7
xcode 12.1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var tasks = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "リスト"
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        if !UserDefaults().bool(forKey: "setup") {
            UserDefaults().set(true, forKey: "setup")
            UserDefaults().set(0, forKey: "count")
        }
        updateTasks()
    }
    
    func updateTasks() {
        
        tasks.removeAll()
        
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        
        for x in 0..<count {

            if let task = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "task_\(x+1)") as? String {
                tasks.append(task)
            }
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapAdd() {
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "entry") as! EntryViewController
        vc.title = "リストに追加"
        vc.update = {
            //非同期処理　更新を優先
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.updateTasks()
            }
        }
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "task") as! TaskViewController
        vc.title = "リストに追加"
        vc.task = tasks[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tasks[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    //タスクを削除
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let index = indexPath.row
        tasks.remove(at: index)
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(tasks, forKey: "tasks")
        userDefaults.removeObject(forKey: "tasks")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class EntryViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!
    var update: (() -> Void)?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        field.delegate = self
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "保存", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(saveTask))
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        saveTask()
        return true
    }
    
    @objc func saveTask() {
        guard let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        guard let count = UserDefaults().value(forKey: "count") as? Int else {
            return
        }
        let newCount = count + 1
        UserDefaults().set(newCount, forKey: "count")
        UserDefaults().set(text, forKey: "task_\(newCount)")
        update?()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserDefaults`のキーに`"tasks"`が使われているのは『タスクを削除』担当の`tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)`内だけで、ほかでは`"task_\(x)"`を使ってデータの保存と読み出しがされているようです。

コードそのものには問題はなさそうなので、キーを`"tasks"`に絞ってやるとうまくいくはずです。

あと`tableView(_:editingStyleForRowAt:)`では `UserDefaults.standard`が使われていますが、ほかは`UserDefaults()`になっているので、特別な理由がなければ`standard`で統一されたほうがいいと思います。

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1416603-standard